How do I call a function from a different activity in my MainActivity.kt
This is the function in my Waves.kt which I want to be able to use in my MainActivity.kt
      var amps = amplitudes.clone() as ArrayList<Float>
      amplitudes.clear()
      spikes.clear()
      invalidate()

      return amps
    } 

this is how I need to use it
amplitudes = Waves.clear()
I saw some question with answers that didn't really help me sadly so I hope someone can help me with this.

Does MainActivity create Waves object or holding an object of class Waves already?

Waves is a class and I need a function i made inside of the Waves class to be used in Main Activity.

I know it's a class, but you have to create an object of Waves class to work with the function: object.clear(), it's called instance level. Or you have to make Waves a Kotlin object so every function of it turns into class level: Waves.clear()

you can use class  -> object
// in waves.kt
object Waves{
    fun get5() :Int{
        return 5
    }
}

// in Mainactivity.kt
val five = Waves.get5()


All the variables in the code become red and not recognized am i supposed to put them all below the object

maybe right click folder -> new -> kotlin class/file -> input className and choose Object.
than input your code like class, is object ,not Object
